# How to show a .gif or message during image loading?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a jsf page that loads an image dynamically. The image generation may take a few seconds, so I would like to display a message or a gif so the user knows something is loading (at the moment there is just an empty space during loading).

I have tried to use primeface's deferred loading, but it made no difference at all.

I have a ajaxStatus in my page, but it is not activated during loading.

Here is the code containing the graphicImage:

```
            <p:outputPanel deferred="true">
                <h:graphicImage
                    value="/wfDiagram?processId=#{workflowAction.processId}"/>
            </p:outputPanel>
```

the `value` is pointing to a servlet that handles image generation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the primefaces `p:blockUI` component. 
Here is some example:

```
<p:blockUI widgetVar="loading" trigger="btnFilterProgram" block=":layout">
    <h:panelGrid styleClass="custom-painelgrid-center">
        <h:outputText value="Loading" />
        <p:graphicImage value="resources/img/loading.gif" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:blockUI>
```

In this case, a kind of "popup dialog" opens when the user clicks the button with the id `btnFilterProgram` and the component closes itself after the AJAX request is finished.

Comment: Rodolfo, that won't work. The image shows up on page load, so there isn't any ajax call.